# Using a carousel pattern to display a set of questions

Tags: design-patterns, carousel, question-answer

I'm considering using the carousel pattern to ask questions in a more dynamic and engaging way (this is my hypothesis). The carousel isn’t the only element on the site and will be displayed at the bottom of the page following a proper formula that should get extended if the carousel idea doesn't work properly. The user can skip through the questions manually.

I’d like to know if folks have used a carousel for this use case, or have any views on the pros and cons this approach.

Here are questions regarding the use of the carousel pattern to display images:
[Using a carousel on home page or not?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/16203/using-a-carousel-on-home-page-or-not/16248#16248)
[How many items in a carousel should be shown to the user at a glance?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/9292/how-many-items-in-a-carousel-should-be-shown-to-the-user-at-a-glance)

The following image shows the typical use case for a carousel (left) and the one I'm considering (right).
[image: The carousel pattern used to display images and questions]

Comment: There is any persistent effect on answering? Can the user change the answers later? Is the next question displayed after answering the current one? How many questions are you willing to fit in the carousel?

Comment: Is the answer always "yes, no, maybe?"

Comment: Thanks for all your questions! @OnofrePouplana  answering the questions in the carousel should be treated like entering input in form fields. To change answers later is possible as long as you're in the same session. After answering a question the next one should be displayed automatically. I consider to use between 6-12 question.

Comment: @DarrylGodden The answers should always be similar short but not exactly the same.

Comment: Is a desired requisite that the user can freely explore and navigate trough all the questions before he commits to answer some of them? If I go back to question one and change the answer...i will be redirected to already answered question two?

Comment: @OnofrePouplana Yes, the user should be able to explore through all the questions and he should be redirected to the next one immediately after answering one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you might be interested in [an existing implementation of carousels for questions](http://blog.brianlovin.com/design-details-foursquare-for-ios/#7). Just hover the animated showcase of how Foursquare has already implemented the same.

This looks good. They have a position indicator telling you the number of remaining panes. On answering, control moves to the next question too. Overall, it is a different way but does what is intended. It is important to have a position indicator and having less number of question in this model.

When you have more questions, the usability starts to diminish, owing to the time wasted in monotonous animations of panes sliding. Soon people get trigger happy about the options they choose. I have seen that happening. Frequent users get irritated because of the sliding wait times (however small they are, they can't beat a simple form with quick selections under a couple of seconds).

Answer (score 0):

We have recently used almost the same concept for building an Android App and it turned out great.The most important thing about the carousel is that a good amount of content can be shown by using minimum space.However you should keep in mind few things :-
1) After selecting the option , user must be able to see the option that he selected before scrolling to the next slide.(You can highlight the selected option)
2) Avoid automatic scrolling as it may confuse users.After selecting the option , user must have the option to proceed to next slide.
Hope that gives you an insight.